# The cursor backspace doesn’t remove last char of number format in react

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I am new to react.
For e.g, input value entered 1,2,3,4 and after the event onChange it takes only numbers, then I can
remove 4,3,2 with backspace but not 1. And in HTML DOM also, the 1 cannot be removed.

```
 class House extends Component {

    state = {
        room: null,
      };

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.props.house.rent) {
          this.setState({ rent: this.props.house.rent });
        }
      }

         onChange = (field, value, mutate) => {
            if (field === "houseroom") {
              value = parseInt(value.replace(/[@,]/g, ""));

            }

         mutate({
              variables: {
              },
            });
 this.setState({
      [field]: value,
    });
          };


            render(){
     const {house} = this.props;
             <SomeInput

                        type="text"
                        value={
                          (house.room&&
                            `$${house.room.toLocaleString("en")}`) ||
                          ""
                        }
                        onChange={e => {
                          e.target.placeholder = "Room";
                          this.onChange("houseroom", e.target.value, mutate);
                        }}

        }
        />

    }
```

Comment: What is in the value field of input tag? Is it coming from state?

Comment: No it is in object format where I am not able to use state. For example <input type = text value = {house.room} />   and  if the value={room} in this format then it works in other example which has no state.

Comment: Hi Vishal, please share the component where the input is being rendered so we can help you better

Comment: okay updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It look like a lot of a problem during the update of the state probably due to overrendering elsewhere in the component try to use prevState instead do ensure that state updating can not conflict.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
             [field]:value; 
    });
```

Keep me in touch with the result.

Comment: Nope Mr.Thibault.Actually the main problem I think is, I am unable to create this :              
        render(){ const {house.room} = this.state; //this gives error as unexpected 
        token , and expected ","     but If I use                                                                                      
        render(){const {house} = this.state; // this has no error.                                             
       So my question is how to create a this.state for {house.room} .   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone !
Need to mention "this.state.room" in the input Value and check the prev state using the componentDidUpdate then "this.setState" here and also finally "this.setState" during the event change. Thanks all